# Case aninhado dentro de outro case

Tags: sql, case, when

Estou com muita dúvida em relação a CASE ANINHADO eu tenho que realizar um cálculo de juros que depende de algumas variáveis e não estou conseguindo montar esse case, então preciso da ajude de vocês para montá-lo.

1º SE **GETDATE()-1** for menor **(<)** que **E1_VENCREA** o código deve parar e colocar o valor **ZERO ( 0 )** pois ainda tem prazo para pagar, senão deve continuar para o **2º QUESITO**.

---

2º Se o resultado do **1º QUESITO** for **FALSO (quer dizer maior)** deve ser verificado se **CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,E1_BAIXA),103** é diferente **(<>)** de **'01/01/1900'**.

---

3º Se o resultado do **2º QUESITO** for **VERDADEIRO** deve ser feito outra verificação se **CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,E1_BAIXA),103)** é maior **(>)** que  **CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,E1_VENCREA),103)**

---

4º Se o resultado do **3º QUESITO** for **VERDADEIRO** realizar o seguinte cálculo **SUM(((E1_PORCJUR/100)*SALDO)*DATEDIFF(DAY,E1_BAIXA,GETDATE()))** se o **3º QUESITO** for **FALSO** realizar esse outro cálculo **SUM(((E1_PORCJUR/100)*SALDO)*DATEDIFF(DAY,E1_VENCREA,GETDATE()))**

---

5º Agora aqui volta para o final do **2º QUESITO** se ele for **FALSO** realizar o seguinte cálculo **SUM(((E1_PORCJUR/100)*SALDO)*DATEDIFF(DAY,E1_VENCREA,GETDATE()))**

---

6º Pronto! agora acabou os quesitos é só nomear a coluna com o nome de **JUROS**.

---

BANCO DE DADOS É O SQL SERVER,
ESTRUTURA DAS TABELAS AQUI [DOWNLOAD TABELAS DROPBOX](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0crf1e39irmpg86/AABqpYl5OacF2CEiC6BjIZCma?dl=0)

Comment: Tem como adicionar a estrutura da tabela? Seja bem vindo, é interessante dá uma lidinha no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor o funcionamento do site.

Comment: Pode editar sua pergunta e posta sua query.

Comment: Informe também o BD em questão pois a síntaxe pode variar

Comment: Pronto, já coloquei as informações que solicitaram.